# Rails nested forms separated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm after some direction in created nested forms operating in their own forms (if that makes sense). I've created some diagrams to help explain what I'm after.

I have the nested forms working fine, I'm just interested to find out if the below is possible.

I know I don't have any code to show, but any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated as I'm not sure where to start.

**Model**

```
class General < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :operation
 belongs_to :report
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_with(model: general, local: true) do |f| %>
 <h1>General</h1>
 <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
 <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
 <%= f.collection_select :property_id, Property.all, :id, :name %>
 <%= f.collection_select :field_id, Field.all, :id, :name %>
 <h1>Operations</h1>
  <%= f.fields_for :operations do |o| %>
  <%= o.text_field :model %>
  <%= o.text_field :type %>
  <%= o.collection_select :status_id, Status.all, :id, :name %>
 <% end %>
 <h1>Reports</h1>
 <%= f.fields_for :report do |r| %>
  <%= r.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= r.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= r.text_area :comments %>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

This is my standard form using nested forms for **Operations** and **Reports** resulting is something like this:

[image]

I'm looking to seperate out the **Operations** and **Reports** forms and place a link available in the General show route.

[image]

The user will click on the **Operations** link and bring up the nested form to edit.

[image]

Comment: You say *The user will click on the Operations link and bring up the nested form to edit* what about create? How do you want to create operations and reports?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I guess you can hide operations and reports using CSS, add two buttons and add an event listener on each of them to display operations form and reports form on click (changing the hidden nested forms CSS).

Comment: Thanks arieljuod. Is this possible? I have seen many tutorials on same page hide/show javascript functions, but not for next/show page applications.

Comment: What do you mean with "next/show page applications"? If I understand what you want, you can wrap operations and reports each on a div, hide them with CSS's `display: none`, then add an `onclick` event listener to each button that changes the `display` property to `block`. I'm not sure what tutorials did you read. Now I see that you are trying to add those blocks on the `show` action, but it's the same, just add the form on the show html too withouth the general fields but with the hidden blocks and links to hide/show them.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was is it possible to have the DOM remember a click on one page to a new page? I'm not to familiar with JS. I haven't come across a tutorial on this yet.

Comment: You will need to use js for that. Showing/hiding forms. Making form editable probably by manipulating form css. So I am suggesting you to read more about javascript / jquery.

Comment: You can pass parameters on the url that you are linking depending on the link clicked. If you are using a form, you can have multiple buttons with type 'submit' to send different values depending on the clicked button. It's hard to suggest something since you have no code.